# While loop function disassembly x86

Tags: ida, x86

I am trying to convert this binary to C but I am having trouble with the while loop. What does
 `sub esp, 8` mean? as well as `push [ebp+_a]` ? I am able to get the esp 8 sometimes while changing the print statement. Why is this the case?

[image: fig1]

What I have so far.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    int a = 9;

    while (a) {

        printf("%d, ");
        --a;
    }
        puts("FIRE!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have the exact same assembly, just have the logic right. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

When the printf function is called (or any other function), it takes all its arguments from the stack. In x86, According to [cdecl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) arguments are pushed in reverse order. So, first the integer value a is pushed on to the top of the stack (`push [ebp+_a]`) and then the string `"%d ,"` is pushed on to the stack (`push offset aD`). While printf pops the arguments out, first it takes out the "%d, " and then it gets the value of a i.e., `[ebp+_a]`. The stack pointer should also be changed accordingly so that the printf function will get the right arguments. Hence the instruction `sub esp, 8` which changes the stack pointer(esp).

Comment: Actually, `sub esp, 8` is there to align the stack on a 16 byte boundary.